# Highcharts PhpMySQL : blank page loads instead of chart - how to render dynamic json data in highcharts

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to load dynamic data to a div. I already have the json data as seen below

```
[{"name":"count","data":[94797,77957,85095,81528,78494]},{"name":"net","data":[270205,220410,237440,227395,217985]},{"name":"principal","data":[4.01,0.14,250677.74,228381.02,219001.12]}]
```

Below is my code. Kindly assist in diagnosing where the issue could be.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
                   var chart;        
       $(document).ready(
                         function() {
                          $.getJSON("graph_dpr.php", 
                        function(json) {

                                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                                            chart: {
                                                renderTo: 'container',
                                                type: 'line',
                                                marginRight: 130,
                                                marginBottom: 25
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'DPR graph',
                                            x: -20 //center
                                        },
                                        subtitle: {
                                            text: '',
                                            x: -20
                                        },
                                        xAxis: {
                                            categories: ['2014-02-01', '2014-02-02', '2014-02-03', '2014-02-04', '2014-02-05']
                                        },
                                        yAxis: {
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'Principal_Lent'
                                            },
                                            plotLines: [{
                                                value: 0,
                                                width: 1,
                                                color: '#808080'
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        tooltip: {
                                            formatter: function() {
                                                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
                                            }
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            layout: 'vertical',
                                            align: 'right',
                                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                                            x: -10,
                                            y: 100,
                                            borderWidth: 0
                                        },
                                        series: json
        });
    });

});
```

});

The chart is supposed to load in the div below inside the body tags.

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Please note that : "graph_dpr.php" is the page where am retrieving the json data.

Comment: Do you use json_encode() with enabled flag JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK? Do you receive any errors in the console (I mean developer tools i.e in Chrome).

Comment: Yes Sebastian, i used them..see code below.   $result = array();

                        array_push($result,$rows);
                        array_push($result,$rows1);
                        array_push($result,$rows2);

               print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: I guess that you use a webserver to get data, becasue $.getJSON doesnt work with local file system.